# How to printscreen and save to local drive in one step in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, print-screen

I know that in winodws 10, you can do win+printscreen, and it saves the entire screen automatically under the picture folder.

Can something similarly be done in Windows 7 please? rather than print to clipboard and go to Paint everytime to save it.

Many thanks

Comment: Using third-party software, anything is possible.

Comment: you know any software that can enable me to do it just by one click/step? because I have to do it probably 100 times a day, working as a validation engineer, we require to save a lot of screenshot for evidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org) app for this. It's a light-weight, open-source, free software.

> **What is Greenshot?**
>
> Greenshot is a light-weight screenshot software tool for Windows with
>   the following key features:
>
> - Quickly create screenshots of a selected region, window or fullscreen; you can even capture complete (scrolling) web pages from
>     Internet Explorer.
> - Easily annotate, highlight or obfuscate parts of the screenshot.
> - Export the screenshot in various ways: save to file, send to printer, copy to clipboard, attach to e-mail, send Office programs or
>     upload to photo sites like Flickr or Picasa, and others.
>
> ...and a lot more options simplyfying creation of and work with
>   screenshots every day.

To configure the app, follow these steps.

1. Go to the Greenshot website and download the app
   https://getgreenshot.org/downloads/
2. After starting the app, right-click the Greenshot icon in the System Tray and select '**Preferences...**'. This should open the setting dialog.
3. In the opened window, go to the '**Destination**' tab (Refer Image 01). Uncheck the '**Select destination dynamically**' option and then check the '**Save directly (using preferred file output settings)**' option.
4. You can also configure the Hotkeys if you want under the '**General**' tab (Refer Image 02).
5. If you need additional help, you can refer to the [help](https://getgreenshot.org/help/) and [FAQ](https://getgreenshot.org/faq/) sections.

If you don't like Greenshot, you might able to find an alternative app such as [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) in here: https://alternativeto.net/software/greenshot/

---

[image: Screenshot 01]
<sup>Image 01: Destination Settings</sup>

[image: Screenshot 02]
<sup>Image 02: General Settings</sup>

Comment: Thanks, looks perfect for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself provides an app known as snipping tool you can find it by following below steps.

- Select the Start button, then type snipping tool in the search box, and then select Snipping Tool from the list of results.

For more details you can follow this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-10-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots).